# Local Area Connections and changing IP Addresses using Visual basic

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I need to be able t view the current local area connections and then click the one you want to change and then change the internal ipaddress as well as gateway and subnet mask using visual basic. I havent found any useful information on the web and I was just wondering if it is possible with visual basic and if so how to do it.. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some Windows scripting. It gets a little messy but you could create the script in VB.Net, write it to your hard drive and then execute it. When done, you can delete the script.

Here is an example of a script that changes the IP Address (and some other related fields): http://www.wincert.net/forum/topic/40-change-ip-configuration-via-vb-script/

Then, you would execute it in VB.Net by calling

```
Process.Start("<The path of your .vbs file here>")
```

Good luck.